# if en un for de jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hola buenas noches es posible hacer un `if` y un `else` dentro de un for de jQuery?:

```
var html = '';
 var i;
 for (i = 0; i < data.pruebas.length; i++) {
   html += '<tr>' +
           '<td> <span class="namePrueba">' +data.pruebas[i].strnombre+ '</span> <br> <span class="conocidoPrueba">' +data.pruebas[i].strconocido+ '</span></td>' +
           '<td>' +data.pruebas[i].ayuno+ '</td>' +
           '<td>' +data.pruebas[i].strprecio+'</td>' +
           '</tr>';
```

Necesito que si el `ata.pruebas[i].ayuno` es igual a 0 Mostrar un html que de un mensaje y si es un `else` mostrar otro mensaje.

Por más que lo pruebe me dice que no puedo utilizar un `if` aquí.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En primeras no veo donde estes usando `jQuery`, para mi el codigo que tienes es todo `javascript` puro, pero supongo lo estaras usando en otra parte de tu codigo el cual no mostraste aqui.

Lo segundo es que apartir de `ES6` existe algo llamado template strings, los cuales tienen ciertas particularidades, una de ellas es que puedes renderizar codigo `javascript` dentro de ellas.

Asi que usemos los `template strings` para tu caso:

```js
var html = '';
var i;

for (i = 0; i < data.pruebas.length; i++) {
    html += 
    `<tr>
      <td>
          <span class="namePrueba">${data.pruebas[i].strnombre}</span><br>
          <span class="conocidoPrueba">${data.pruebas[i].strconocido}</span>
      </td>
      <td>${data.pruebas[i].ayuno == 0 ? "un mensaje" : "otro mensaje"}</td>
      <td>${data.pruebas[i].strprecio}</td>
    </tr>
    `;
}
```

Donde la condicion que indicas:

> data.pruebas[i].ayuno sea mayor a cero

Esta siendo renderizada de esta manera en un **shorthand if** en el `HTML`:

```
${data.pruebas[i].ayuno == 0 ? "un mensaje" : "otro mensaje"}
```

Lo que se traduce a:

`data.pruebas[i]` es igual a cero?, si es asi renderiza el string `"un mensaje"` en la cadena, de lo contrario (else) renderiza `"otro mensaje"` por supuesto estas cadenas son reemplazables con `HTML` que necesites, solo puse de ejemplo eso.

Comment: Funciona perfectamente @Riven , muchas gracias ;)

Comment: Una pregunta más y si tengo que comparar más de uno, en este caso 4, según valor muestro una cosa u otra @Riven

Comment: @Miguel recuerda que dentro de los template strings `\`\`` puedes renderizar directamente codigo javascript, y los shorthand ifs normalmente no utilizas mas de una condicion o 2, si requieres mas de dos condiciones lo que deberias hacer es directamente crear una variable y cambiarle su valor con diferentes condiciones `if` - `else` renderizadas dentro del template string, que recuerda que puedes renderizar codigo `JS` dentro de: `${}`